# two pairs with same max sum in c

Tags: algorithm

Given an array a[].Find the two pairs (a,b) and (c,d) such that a+b==c+d.And the sum (a+b==c+d)value as maximum as possible we just have to print that sum value if it is forming the two pairs with same sum value else -1

Note->NO cpp only c language allowed which makes this problem more difficult for me

Example: N = 6, S[] = { 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5 } You can select pair of (6, 3) and (5, 4), two numbers can be same ,but same number can not be part of both pair.

My Thinking 1 -> I tried to make all possible pairs store the pairs sum in sorted array ,then i started searching form end to check if it is possible that we can find two teams with maxsum But unable to handle like case 0 0 1 1(which contain duplicates)

My Thinking 2 ->all ways to choose 1st, 2nd and 3rd student and check whether you have 4th one with skill equal to (S1+S2−S3)? And then choose maximum among all possible teams. But since n<=500 it will be O(n^4) can give TLE.

please help!

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use pairs (a, b) as being:

- a: the index of a number in the array
- b: the index of other number in the array (a != b)

Let's create a dictionary D to store lists of those pairs. If a pair (a, b) is such that S[a] + S[b] = 10, then (a, b) should be included in the list D[S[a] + S[b]].

That means that the key to find a pair in D is the sum of both elements represented by this pair in the original array.

If another pair (c, d) also satisfies S[c] + S[d] = 10, then (c, d) would be in the same list D[S[a] + S[b]].

We can iterate through the array and save all pairs in their correct lists:

```
for(int i = 0; i < |S| - 1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < |S|; j++){
        D[S[i] + S[j]].Add( new pair(i, j) );
    }
}
```

With your dictionary filled, you have a lot of lists of pairs whose sum (in the original array) is the same. For each key k (that represents a sum), ask if the length of the list D[k] is at least 2, which means there are at least 2 pairs holding that same sum. If it is, search for a two pairs in the list that don't have anyone in common, this will be your answer. Search from the biggest key to the smallest for better performance. This approach is O(n²).

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward algorithm:

```
 1) Find all two-sized subset of the array and their sums (n(n-1)/2)
 2) Now, sort these \Theta(n^2) numbers in \Theta(n^2 log(n))
 3) Then traverse this list in descending order two find duplicates 
 4) This duplicate value in sums could be reported as a result
```

Hence, the problem could be solved in `\Theta(n^2 log(n))`.